# Runtime error '1004' General odbc error while refreshing excel sheet to get updated data

Tags: vba, excel, odbc, excel-2010

We are using shared folder in server where we keep all excel sheets based on our business requirement so whoever requires that document he will picked up that document from that shared folder and he will receive all update/manipulated data by clicking on "Refresh" button in "Data" tab in excel 2007,so in my organization everybody pc is working fine and they are getting updated data by refreshing document but in my pc the movement i click on refresh i am getting this error which is in image below please provide me a clear answer.

```
Sub TT_Out()
' ' Macro2 Macro

Dim RngFromDate, RngToDate
RngFromDate = InputBox("Enter Start Date !", "TT Out", Date - 1)
RngToDate = InputBox("Enter End Date !", "TT Out", RngFromDate)

With Range("Table_Query_from_ALXORCL[TT_OUT_DATE]").ListObject.QueryTable
    .Connection = Array(Array( _
        "ODBC;DRIVER={Oracle in instantclient_12_1};" & _
              "SERVER=ALXORCL;UID=ALXLIVE;PWD=alx123;" & _
              "DBQ=ALXORCL;DBA=W;APA=T;EXC=F;XSM=Default;FEN=T;QTO=T;FRC=10;F"), _
        Array("DL=10;LOB=T;RST=T;BTD=F;BNF=F;BAM=IfAllSuccessful;NUM=NLS;" & _
              "DPM=F;MTS=T;MDI=Me;CSR=F;FWC=F;FBS=60000;TLO=O;" & _
              "MLD=0;ODA=F;STE=F;TSZ=8"), Array("192;"))
    .CommandText = Array( _
        " SELECT ALX_TT_OUT.TT_OUT_CODE, " & _
        "        ALX_TT_OUT.TT_OUT_DATE, " & _
        "        ALX_TT_OUT.F_NAME, " & _
        "        ALX_TT_OUT.B_F_NAME, " & _
        "        ALX_TT_OUT.SENDING_PRPS, " & _
        "        ALX_LOOKUP_DET.LOOKUP_DET_NAME||'-'||ALX_TT_OUT.DOC_NO, " & _
        "        ALX_PRODUCT.PRODUCT_CODE, " & _
        "        ALX_TT_OUT.QTY*ALX_TT_OUT.SELL_RATE, " & _
        "        ALX_CORRESPONDENT.CORRESPONDENT_NAME" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & _
        " FROM ALXTEST.ALX_CORRESPONDENT ALX_CORRESPONDENT, ALXTEST2.ALX_LOOKUP_DET ALX_LOOKUP_DET, ALXTEST2.ALX_PRODUCT ALX_PRODUCT, ALXL", _
        "      IVE.ALX_TT_OUT ALX_TT_OUT" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & _
        " WHERE ALX_PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID = ALX_TT_OUT.PRODUCT_ID " & _
        "   AND ALX_TT_OUT.CORRESPONDENT_ID = ALX_CORRESPONDENT.CORRESPONDENT_ID " & _
        "   AND ALX_LOOKUP_DET.LOOKUP_DET_ID = ALX_TT_OUT.DOC_TYPE_L ", _
        "   AND ((ALX_TT_OUT.TT_OUT_CODE Not Like '%HOF%') " & _
        "         AND (to_date(TT_OUT_DATE) Between '" & RngFromDate & "' And '" & RngToDate & "') " & _
        "        )")
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Next time you might want to consider formatting your code before posting it. Just by doing so you can easily read the code (and the SQL command within) and see all possible problems. Especially the SQL command seems to be a bit off. To resolve the issue I'd copy the SQL command into an SSMS (or whatever SQL server you are using) and verify the command actually runs there without errors.

Comment: I don't have oracle/SQL in pc installed i am just accessing it through oracle instant client and connect oracle database in excel 2010 every thing is working fine i am able to connect with oracle but the problem is when i want updated data and i click on refresh button i am getting this error so is there any procedure to handle it.

Comment: Step (1) debug the connection, step (2) debug the SQL, step (3) combine the two and see if it works, step (4) record the combination of the two with the macro recorder to get the correctly working VBA code. Note, that everything before step (4) can be done **without** VBA in the `Data` tab / menu of Excel.